# Passing default parameters into nested functions python

Tags: python, nested, parameter-passing, default

I have a function

```
foo(x, setting1=def1, settings2=def2)
```

(actually this is a third party library function with a bunch of default parameters of which I need to set only 1 externally, but for the sake of example..)

I am calling this from

```
bar(y, settings2_in=def2)
   x = get_x(y)
   foo(x, settings2=settings2_in)
```

This is ok, but stylistically I'd rather call name the parameter `settings2_in` `settings2`. When I keep passing another layer down, I'll have to keep renaming the parameter, and it gets ugly.

```
bletch(z, settings2_in_2=def2)
   y = get_y(z)
   bar(y, settings2_in=settings_in_2)
```

Is there a "nice"/Pythonic way to pass a subset of default parameters down many layers of functions in this way?

Is Python clever enough to work out that if I do:

```
bar(y, settings2=def2)
   x = get_x(y)
   foo(x, settings2=settings2)
```

That the 2 uses of `settings2` are different from the context?

Comment: just `bar(y, **kwargs)` then `foo(x, **kwargs)` I guess

Comment: **kwargs looks like the way to do it nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly: yes, Python is clever enough to not confuse a local variable and an outbound function parameter with the same name. Example:

```
def x(a):
    ...

def y(a, b):
    return x(a=a)
```

In the return line, the right-hand `a` is the local variable from the parameter passed into function `y` and the left-hand `a` is the parameter to function `x`.

Names of parameters to called functions are in the namespace of the called function's parameter list, which is unrelated to the local and global variables of the calling context.

Comment: Great - I probably should just have tested it, but it's nice to know for sure, thanks

Comment: I see you are a new StackOverflow user, one hint -- once you decide which answer is most helpful to you, use the check mark to accept that answer.

Answer (score 3):

you could avoid redefining all the parameters in your functions, just use `**kwargs` to capture all keyword arguments.

Then pass the keyword arguments to your `foo` function

```
def foo(x, setting1="def1", settings2="def2"):
    print(setting1,settings2)


def bar(y,**kwargs):
    foo(y,**kwargs)

bar(12)
bar(y=12)
bar(12,setting1="other")
```

result:

```
def1 def2
def1 def2
other def2
```

note that since `y` is outside `kwargs`, passing `y` as keyword also works.

the only drawback is that you don't know what can be actually passed to `bar`, but it's logical as it depends on what `foo` accepts. Make that up by adding a docstring to your function.